# New cosmology tag?

Tags: support, specific-tag, tags

I am thinking of adding a new tag that might be helpful in Worldbuilding. One of the tags I am think of at the moment is cosmology.

**Cosmology**

> For questions about the creation and development of the universe. This tag is different from the astronomy tag because it has to do with creation theory, not observation of astronomical events.

More info:

> [Cosmology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmology) is a branch of science dealing with understanding the creation of the universe. The most popular of creation theories is the [Big Bang Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang). The Big Bang is a hypothetical scenario in which an infinitely small sphere containing all of the mass in the universe exploded outward, eventually forming galaxies and stars. As with all theories in cosmology, this theory has problems explaining the universe, such as why the universe appears to be expanding faster. Another theory in cosmology is [Steady state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steady_state_model), which proposes that galaxies are created in the center of the universe and expand outwards. The density of matter in the universe remains constant, but this theory breaks the [law of conservation of mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_of_mass). The cosmology tag can be used to describe both scientific and religious interpretations of the creation of the universe, although a religion tag is recommended for the latter.

I was looking at a post and thinking "I could add a few tags to this," but when I looked for those tags, I realized they didn't exist. Specifically, it was [this post](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22957/religion-after-the-discovery-of-a-multiverse).

I am not wondering if it is possible to add these tags or how to add them, I have the rep to do so. What I am wondering is whether I should. Will adding this tag be helpful to other users? I have read the help section about tags, and it says:

> As a general rule, you should avoid creating new tags if possible, and new users are not allowed to create new tags. Even if you have sufficient reputation, you should only create new tags when you feel you can make a strong case that your question covers a new topic that nobody else has asked about before on this site.

I don't this tag would be particularly novel, but I think they would help users search for questions about topics they like. For example, someone who is really interested in cosmology in particular could search for questions with that topic.

Also, I have ideas for some possible tags that could also be created but that I won't get into just yet:

string theory, astrology, separate tags for creation theories (eg: one for the Big Bang etc.)

I want to see what other users think about the first two tags first before I consider these tags, though.

**Should I create this tag**, or would it just be more noise on the site? It would be great to hear what people's opinions are on this.

Comment: This should perhaps be two questions - the answers may well be different in each case.

Comment: Ok, I'm new to creating tags. I'll make another question and edit this one.

Comment: Do you have a tag description in mind?  If you do you should post it so we can understand the intent of the new tag.

Comment: @James Clarified with an edit

Comment: @James Added an additional info section here too

Comment: I think it's a good idea! There doesn't seem to be any overlap with other tags, as you say.